# Prove that $\int_x^{1} \frac{dx}{1+x^{2}} =\int_{1}^{\frac{1}{x}} \frac{dx}{1+x^{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I want to prove the following equality $$\int_x^{1} \frac{dx}{1+x^{2}} =\int_{1}^{\frac{1}{x}} \frac{dx}{1+x^{2}}$$

My idea is to test this through the use of partitions, for this purpose I proposed the following

Let $P=(x=t_0,t_1,..., t_n=1)$ an interval partition $[x,1]$ and be $$m_i=inf(\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}: t_{i-1}≤x≤t_i)$$ and $$M_i=sup(\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}: t_{i-1}≤x≤t_i)$$

Considering also $P'=(1=t_0,t_1,..., t_n=\frac{1}{x})$ an interval partition $[1,\frac{1}{x}]$ and be $$m_i'=inf(\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}: t_{i-1}≤x≤t_i)$$ and $$M_i'=sup(\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}: t_{i-1}≤x≤t_i)$$

Well, I am not clear if the above choice is suitable added to the fact that I don't know how to continue with the test, any help please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\int_{x}^{1} \frac{1}{1+ t^2} = \int_{1}^{\frac{1}{x}} \frac{1}{1+ t^2}$ for $x \gt 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3753851/prove-that-int-x1-frac11-t2-int-1-frac1x-frac11-t)

Comment: Of course you’ve committed the sin of using the same letter , $x$, for the dummy (bound) variable in the integral as for the limit. Beyond that, following @AndréArmatowski , I ask whether you know the antiderivative (indefinite integral) $\int\!\!\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$.

Comment: Partitions might work, but they must be the hardest way. What happens when you substitute $u=1/x$?